# how i can get the image FileSize of Image already loaded in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

Normally to find the file size of an image we use:

```
info = imfinfo('image.jpg');
sizeOfImage = info.FileSize;
```

After I reconstruct the image with different Eigenvalues I need to get the file size before writing a file with `imwrite(A,filename)`

Thanks for help.

Comment: You don't need the file size to save with `imwrite`. Is there any particular reason you require file size _before_ saving? If so, the size will depend on the file format, and this may not be trivial. If not, you can save and then check the file size after.

Comment: Oky i got your point Thank you